# How to open an image in gallery with sliding behavior in android with Intent

Tags: android, image, android-intent, slide, android-gallery

I am opening an image in gallery app with intent in android. For that I am using content provider to get uri and starts an intent to view that uri

```
 val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent.setDataAndType(photoURI,"image/*")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(intent)
```

But it only opens the single image (of my uri). I don't get the slide behavior which is usually seen in gallery apps. Is there any specific intent or intent filter to open an image in gallery with slide behavior?